# choosing the right design pattern for service which connects to thirdparty

Tags: web-services, symfony, design-patterns, soap

I was wondering if someone could help please, so I need to identify the correct design pattern to use and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

So basically I am using symfony2, I am using a bundle to handle my soap request to a third party api for identity check on users but I need to build the service, build the xml for the soap request and add some additional stuff to the user entity which contains the identity check collection.

I am stuck on how to properly build the service, how can I make the service third party agnostic ? Do I create a service interface with I can then use to generate a thirdparty specific service ? Then do I build an entity which is mapped to the result from the third party but again should this be an interface I extend for specific third parties ?

There must be a design pattern for this but I have no idea what to even google or look for.

Thanks in advance.

**Addition**

I am thinking maybe I could use the Bridge pattern but again not 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to implements a Factory Method and let Symfony instantiate the correct class for you (as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html) ).
Like this example:

Suppose you have a Simple (external) Service that you can define as an interface:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Service\Integration;


interface ExternalServiceInterface  {

    public function call($object)
}
```

And define a factory like this:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Service\Integration;

class ESServiceFactory {

    /**
     * @var array of integration strategy
     * key   = strategy key name
     * value = service implements the behaviour
     */
    protected $services;

    function __construct($services)
    {
        $this->services=$services;
    }

    /**
     * @param $type: strategy key name
     * @return \Acme\DemoBundle\Service\Integration\ExternalServiceInterface;
     */
    public function get($type)
    {
        return $this->services[$type];
    }
}
```

and define the services as:

services.yml

```
services:

# The real Soap Services
  acme.integration.soap:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Service\Integration\ExternalServiceSoapCaller
        arguments: [%acme.soap_base_url%, %acme.api_key%, @logger]

# Mocked service: response with fixed value (true). For tests pourpose
  acme.integration.es_a_true:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Service\Tests\ExternalServiceMock
        arguments: [true]

# Mocked service: response with fixed value (true). For tests pourpose
  acme.integration.es_false:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Service\Tests\ExternalServiceMock
        arguments: [false]


  sd_factory:
        class:            Acme\DemoBundle\Service\Integration\ESServiceFactory
        arguments:
          -service_available:
            'SOAP': @acme.integration.soap
            'MOCK_ALWAYS_TRUE': @acme.integration.es_a_true
            'MOCK_ALWAYS_FALSE': @acme.integration.es_a_false


  external_service_manager:
        class:            "Acme\DemoBundle\Service\Integration\ExternalServiceInterface"
        factory_service:  sd_factory
        factory_method:   get
        arguments: [%params_defined_in_parametes_yml%]
```

In practice you define in the parameters what strategy you want, like 'SOAP' or a mocked response and you in your controller/service like:

```
$response = $this->get('external_service_manager')->call($obj);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver, I hope to have center your question or have inspired you on the right way for solve your problem. This is only an approach to a problem with pro&cons. I'm Waiting for more other opinion and answer on your question!